# Trying to get user input to be between two values

Tags: java

I am trying to prompt the user to enter a value between 1 and 12. If they enter a value outside this range (EX -15) I need to continue prompting till they enter a value with in the of 1-12. Also when a user enters a value between the range specified (1-12) It needs to print a times table with the results of multiplying the integers 1 through the input number. So far I believe I have the layout some what correct but I know I'm missing something but can't figure out what here's the code:

```
package times_Table;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Times_Table {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int TOTAL = 5;

        System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 12:");
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        int numbers = input;

        //If the input is out of the range 1-12 keep going
        //If the input is in the range of 1-12 stop

        //Need to find a way to keep looping if the integer inputed is     out of the range 1-12
        while (numbers>1 && numbers<12) {
            if (numbers<1 && numbers>12) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= TOTAL; i++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j<=TOTAL; j++) {
                        System.out.print(i*j + "\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            } else {
                if (numbers < 1 && numbers > 12) {
                    System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 12:");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help you a lot if you would step through the code in your IDE debugger and watch what is happening at each statement.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: You need to rework your `if/else` flow. It should be if the number is inside, do the math, otherwise, ask for input again with `Scanner`. Right now your while loop is making the if else loop useless.

Comment: Mind to clarify the *It needs to print a times table with the results of multiplying the integers 1 through the input number...*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the while like this:

```
while (keepGoing) {
    while (numbers < 1 || numbers > 12) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 12:");
        numbers = sc.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j<=numbers; j++) {
            System.out.print(i*j + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jordy this helped.

Comment: So glad my answer helped. Excuse me but I did not understand this "It needs to print a times table with the results of multiplying the integers 1 through the input number." (Sorry, english is not my mother's tongue)

Comment: When a value in the range is entered in needs to print out a time table with that many rows and columns. EX say I use 2 as the number in range a time table shows up with 2 rows and 2 columns. So far I have it set to default of 5 no matter what final int TOTAL = 5;

Comment: @Rocko1234 I just edited my answer to print what you want. I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jordy and Cricket

Answer (score 1):

The recommended pattern for a repeating prompt would be a do-while loop.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int input;
do {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 12: ");
    input = sc.nextInt();

    if (input < 1 || input >= 12) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number input!");
    }
} while (input < 1 || input >= 12);
```

And this prints a table

```
for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= input; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%3d\t", i*j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Like so

```
Enter an integer between 1 and 12: 11
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11 
  2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22 
  3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33 
  4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44 
  5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55 
  6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66 
  7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77 
  8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88 
  9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99 
 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 
 11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99 110 121
```